# MongoDB aggregation to return nested groups with values as keys?

Tags: mongodb

My documents look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "Tvq579754r",
        "Status" : "passed",
        "Title" : "up08c",
        "ProjectID" : "Tvq5p",
        "Version" : "1.0.0",
        "Platform" : "platform_x",
        "METRIC_A" : 11114.85,
        "METRIC_B" : 68.9,
        "METRIC_C" : 65.35,
},
{
        "_id" : "Tvq579755r",
        "Status" : "passed",
        "Title" : "up09c",
        "ProjectID" : "Tvq5p",
        "Version" : "1.0.0",
        "Platform" : "platform_x",
        "METRIC_A" : 21114.85,
        "METRIC_B" : 168.9,
        "METRIC_C" : 165.35,
},
{
        "_id" : "Tvq579756r",
        "Status" : "passed",
        "Title" : "up09c",
        "ProjectID" : "Tvq5p",
        "Version" : "1.0.0",
        "Platform" : "platform_x",
        "METRIC_A" : 31114.85,
        "METRIC_B" : 268.9,
        "METRIC_C" : 265.35,
}
```

Now I have no problem grouping and getting `$avg` and `$sum` of my `METRIC_` fields by grouping by `ProjectID`, `Version`, `Platform` and `Title`, but what I'd like to do within the aggregation framework (if possible) is to return an object that **uses the grouped values as keys**, such as:

```
{ 
        <Project ID> : {
                <Version> : {
                        <Platform> : {
                                <Title> : {
                                        "METRIC_A": <sum of METRIC_A>,
                                        "METRIC_B": <sum of METRIC_B>,
                                        "METRIC_C": <sum of METRIC_C>,
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Or, in context of my example:

```
{ 
        'Tvq5p' : {
                '1.0.0' : {
                        'platform_x' : {
                                'up08c' : {
                                        "METRIC_A": 11114.85,
                                        "METRIC_B": 68.9,
                                        "METRIC_C": 65.35,
                                },
                                'up09c' : {
                                        "METRIC_A": 52229.7,
                                        "METRIC_B": 437.8,
                                        "METRIC_C": 430.7,
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I am currently doing it once the query results are received by the consuming service, which isn't terribly slow or anything, but I just thought it would be nice to come that way right out of Mongo. Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: there is a feature request to allow this to happen in $project phase, please vote it up!  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB there is the [group operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/group/).

```
db.records.group( {
   key: { 'platform_x': 1, 'title': 1 },
   reduce: function(cur, result) { 
     result.metric_a += cur.metric_a;
     result.metric_b += cur.metric_b;
     result.metric_c += cur.metric_c;
   },
   initial: { metric_a = 0, metric_b = 0, metric_c = 0 }
 } )
```

If that doesn't work I'd recommend a [Map Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/).